# Per-member public/protected/private?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to write e.g.

```
class A 
{
public:
    int A;
    int B;
    private int C;
};
```

Sometimes this would be quite handy to clean up the code. If not, any ideas why?

Comment: "ideas why" Because this syntax is not a part of C++?

Comment: Why hasn't it been added? Quite some obscure stuff is being added to C++ all the time, and this seems simple to implement and quite useful.

Comment: @mrzacekmrzacek: All your code needs is a colon after `private` and it works. Also, it's rather... dubious to have both public and private non-static data members. In most objects, you usually have all of one or the other. Either the type encapsulates its data or it doesn't.

Comment: @NicolBolas well, yes, but then you need to repeat the public. And that makes the code clumsy. If you have a big class with lots of members, and start to structure them by sort of "section", this becomes a real hog. As you know e.g. C# has this, so it is known to have benefits. My question was more like if there is a reason this hasn't been included.

Comment: If you think it's useful, try to write a proposal to the committee (and most probably watch it going down in flames).

Comment: @mrzacekmrzacek: "*As you know e.g. C# has this*" No, C# requires that you explicitly qualify *all* members. C++ does not.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has no construct to make just one member of a different access class. If you need that, just put a colon after `private` and the code will work just fine. You will need to re-institute `public` if you want to add more public members after the `private` one.

Comment: Well of course, but the repeat of "public" is the problem...

Comment: But you say "C# has this (repetition)" as if it's a benefit. So if you like that, do it in C++ too, consistently.